# How do I get this function to run synchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

async await is very confusing. I have the below code and here I am trying to implement a create user function that first needs to check if the user exists in my MySQL database. I have the initial setting of the user where I call await on my findByUsername function. However, The function finishes after my if(!user) code has been executed.

I want the program to wait for the findByUsername function to finish and then perform the check on whether the user exists or not.

```
    const { username, password, firstname, permission } = req.body;
    let user = await User.findByName(req.body.username, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            if (err.kind === "not_found") {
                console.log("finished");
                return null;
            } else {
                console.error("error occurred");
            }
        } else {
            console.log("finished too");
            return data;
        }
    });
    if (!user) {
        console.log("couldnt find user");
        res.status(404).send("couldnt find it :(");
    } else {
        console.log("found user");
        res.send("found them");
    }
```

===EDIT===
I am getting another that has also been confusing me where it says that result is not a function inside of my findByName function on my User model.

```
    sql.query(`SELECT * from users WHERE username = '${username}'`, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error ", err);
            result(err, null);
            return;
        }
        if (res.length) {
            console.log("found user: ", res[0]);
            result(null, res[0]);
            return;
        }
        console.log("couldnt find");
        return { kind: "not_found" }, null;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We must use `await` inside an `async` function.

For example:

```js
const getUser = async (username) => await User.findByName(username);
```

Then call that function inside a try catch

```js
try {
    user = getUser(someUsername)
} catch (error) {
    // Handle errors here
}

// Code here will only run once getUser is finished
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked however I'm now getting another error on my findByName function. See the edit above do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: @archhmod If the solution worked, could you please mark the answer as accepted? 

About the other issue, maybe a new question would be more appropriate, since the issue here was related to async code, however, sounds like a scope problem. Without seeing more of your code is hard to say, but try checking where you are defining the function. Again, creating another question with a more details will probably be more effective.

Answer (score 1):

Since i don't know your UserService i don't know if "User.FindByName" is a async function. but if that is the case you could do it like this:

```
const { username, password, firstname, permission } = req.body;
try {
  let user = await User.findByName(req.body.username);
  if (!user) {
    console.log("couldnt find user");
    res.status(404).send("couldnt find it :(");
  } else {
    console.log("found user");
    res.send("found them");
  }
} catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to change the definition of `User.findByName`?

Instead of using `await` and also passing in a callback, why not remove the callback and process it synchronously?

```
let user = await User.findByName(username);
// Handle response here
```

Answer (score 0):

this will solve your Problem If you are using sequelize with mysql you can use where
condition in your code so you can use more conditions in it

```
  const { username, password, firstname, permission } = req.body;

  try {
  let user = await User.findOne({
            where: { username: req.body.username },
            attributes: { exclude: ['password', 'signup_token'] }
        });

        if (!user) {
            console.log("couldnt find user");
            res.status(401).send("couldnt find user with username" + 
            (req.body.username));
        } else {
            console.log("User Found");
            return res.status(200).send("User Found With Username" + 
            (req.body.username));
        }
      } catch (error){
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).send(error);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

> The function finishes after my if(!user) code has been executed.

That is because you are mixing async/await with callbacks which you should not.

```js
// Here you are mixing async/await and callbacks
let user = await User.findByName(req.body.username, (err, data) => { /*....*/ });

// it is the same as 
function findByNameCallback(err, data) { /*.....*/ }
let user = await User.findByName(req.body.username, findByNameCallback);

// -- So you either remove the callback from the equation
var user;
try {
  user = await User.findByName(req.body.username);
} catch (err) {
  // Handle error
}
// Work with the user object...
// ----

// Or remove the async/await stuff
User.findByName(req.body.username, findByNameCallback);
```